# Fade in appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending DOM to some element in an interval, I want it to fade in, but it seems that it first apears, then disappears, and only then fade in is run.

```
var el = document.getElementById('cont');
el.innerHTML = '';
var toAppend = getElementsToAppend();
$(el).hide().append(toAppend).fadeIn(300);
```

How should I do this smoothly?

Comment: Can you give the `toAppend`  a `display:none;` before you append it, then fade it in?

Comment: Try to add `display: none;' to the `#cont` element instead of hiding it from jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you seem to have an mix of native JS and jQuery methods. I'd suggest sticking with one or the other as much as possible. Also note that you're calling `fadeIn()` on the `$(el)`, not on the content that was appended to the DOM.

Presuming that `elementsToAppend()` returns an array of DOMElements, you can put them all in a single jQuery selector and call `hide()` on them, before you call `fadeIn()` after appending. Try this:

```
var $toAppend = $(getElementsToAppend()).hide();
$('#cont').empty().append($toAppend);
$toAppend.fadeIn(300);
```